# Limit user integer input to 8 digits

Tags: python, integer, limit

I have this little credit card validation program where the user has to input an 8 digit integer. The program works fine, my only problem seems to be limiting user input to 8 digits only.

```
prompt = "Please, enter the 8 digit number of your card: "

while True: 
    try:
        userinput = int(raw_input(prompt))
    except ValueError: 
        print('The gematric value must be an 8 digit integer. Try again')
    else:
        break 

userinput = str(userinput)

a = int(userinput[7])+int(userinput[5])+int(userinput[3])+int(userinput[1])
b1 = str(int(userinput[6])*20)
b2 = str(int(userinput[4])*20)
b3 = str(int(userinput[2])*20)
b4 = str(int(userinput[0])*20)
y = int(b1[0])+int(b1[1])+int(b2[0])+int(b2[1])+int(b3[0])+int(b3[1])+int(b4[0])+int(b4[1])

x = (a+y)

if x % 10 == 0:
   print('The card number you entered is valid!')
else:
   print('The card number you entered is invalid!')
```

I know len() does not work with integers. So how would i incorporate that 8 digit limit into my while true loop?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following.

```
try:
    userinput = raw_input(prompt)
    if len(userinput ) > 8:
        raise ValueError()
    userinput = int(userinput)
except ValueError:
...
```

Comment: Great, i just changed > to != and it works perfect. Thank you.