# Python looping and printing continously when not needed

Tags: python

I basically have a currency exchange on python but im trying to limit the users input to 4 digits, when i try it, it loops continously and prints the number you have just inputed. Please help. Here is part of the programme :

```
amount=input('\nPlease input the amount of '+ numtoletter + '\'s you have : ' + symbol)
while True:  
    try:
        amount1 = input(amount)
        if len(amount1) > 4:
            raise ValueError()
        amount1 = int(amount1)
    except ValueError: 
        print('The maximum number of ' + currencyfrom + ' is ' + symbol + '9999 please try again')
    else:
        break
```

Please input the amount of pound sterling's you have : £22222

22222

The maximum number of 1 is £9999 please try again

22222

The maximum number of 1 is £9999 please try again

22222

The maximum number of 1 is £9999 please try again

THE BELOW IS JUST SHOWING WHAT IS numtoletter

```
if currencyto== '1':
    numtoletter1 = 'pound sterling'
elif currencyto == '2':
    numtoletter1 = 'euro'
elif currencyto == '3':
    numtoletter1 = 'us dollar'
elif currencyto =='4':
    numtoletter1 = 'japanese yen'
```

currencyto and currency from it either pound sterling, euro, us dollar, japanese yen

i used [Limit user integer input to 8 digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936683/limit-user-integer-input-to-8-digits) to help me with it and this is where i got part of the code from

SOLVED IT :

```
while True: 
    try:
        amount1 = input('please enter the amount : ')
        if len(amount1) < 4:
            amount2 = amount1*4
            break
    except ValueError: 
        print('Opps, incorrect amount. Please retry')
```

Comment: What's your specific problem/question?

Comment: The line `amount1 = input(amount)` is *really* weird.

Comment: You could post your actual code as a start. "I only go up to xxx digits.." is not in your code at all.

Comment: I'd misread your indentation in my answer. As others have indicated, we'd need to see more code to know what's wrong.

Comment: I suggest [you answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).